# Get the order of applictaions on GUI

Tags: command-line, scripts, gui, window

Is there a command to show the order of application shows on GUI?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a different version of ALT+TAB?

Comment: No, I am asking a command that shows the order of applications on GUI. Use the picture as an example, the command windows is on top of GUI, so the order is 1.

Comment: Could you explain about the use case?

Comment: May not be possible if your window manager does not explicitly expose a way to query this: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214093/get-window-list-sorted-by-most-recent-access-bash

Comment: Speaking of, what is your window manager? Wayland? Mutter?

Comment: Hi 王柏翔 curious if a) this is what you mean, and b) if you need any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, my guess is you are looking for a way to achieve it in python.

### Get the z-order of windows

**If you are on X**, you can use (in any language that has bindings to - ) Wnck. Wnck does not work on Wayland though. The snippet below shows how it's done in python. The order of the output list is in the order of the window z-order. 
Note that the output of `Wnck.get_windows_stacked()` [should not be modified](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Screen.html#Wnck.Screen.get_windows_stacked). You can of course work with the data, retrieved from it, get the order of the windows and their properties. In the snippet, I only used to get the xid and name of the window, but [a lot is possible](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Wnck-3.0/classes/Window.html#Wnck.Window).

### Example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Wnck

def get_stack():
    z_order_list = []
    scr = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
    # if Wnck is not called from withing a Gtk loop, we need:
    scr.force_update()
    for w in scr.get_windows_stacked():
        # most likely, we only work with normal windows (no panels or desktop)
        if w.get_window_type() == Wnck.WindowType.NORMAL:
            # only adding xid and name here, but anything is possible
            z_order_list.append([w.get_xid(), w.get_name()])
    z_order_list.reverse()
    return z_order_list

wlist = get_stack()
for w in wlist:
    print(w[0], w[1])
```

Example output:

```
92306612 *IDLE Shell 3.8.10*
92274937 zorder.py - /home/jacob/Bureaublad/zorder.py (3.8.10)
96468995 Get the order of applictaions on GUI - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
98568913 Geen titel 1 - LibreOffice Writer
98566678 Rooster Jacob 2021-2022.ods - LibreOffice Calc
94371847 Tilix: jacob@jacob-ZN220IC-K:~
```

where the first is the most recent window, because I reversed the list.

Note that Gdk [has similar method](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/classes/Screen.html#Gdk.Screen.get_window_stack).